# Count occurrences in a column and get the whole line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

```
Trio type1 Chr Pos Allele rsID Gene
Sample11 type1 1 11105106 C/T rs2273345 MASP2
Sample11 type1 1 31342388 A/C/* 1:31342388 SDC3
Sample11 type1 1 33402334 GA/G-/++A rs36040674 RNF19B
Sample11 type1 1 38078171 G/+GT/+GTGT rs139353088 RSPO1
Sample11 type1 1 47074774 TCATGGTCTGATGGTCC/T----------------/ACATGGTCTGATGGTCC rs4275405 MOB3C
Sample11 type1 1 50883804 CTT/C--/CT- 1:50883804 DMRTA2
Sample11 type1 1 52947350 TA/++A/T- 1:52947350 ZCCHC11
Sample11 type1 1 84956161 CT/C-/++T rs556742567 RPF1
Sample11 type1 1 114940632 CAA/C--/CA- rs78184484 TRIM33
```

I know how to count the occurrence of column rsID. 
Here is the command I learn from @glenn jackman, which I can have the count of each rsID.

```
awk '{count[$7]++} END {for (word in count) print word, count[word]}' Nofilter.txt
```

I would like to grep the whole line which the rsID is recurrent.

```
grep if count[word]>3
```

How should I modify the command based on the current one ?

Comment: grep what? do you want to print lines where the count is greater than some number?

Comment: Yes, maybe grep is not a good idea ? @karakfa

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- You are using gawk, and
- Out-of-order output is OK, and
- Your input is named `data.txt`

Solutions:

- Since gawk 4.0.0:

  ```
  awk '{a[$7]++;b[$7][c++]=$0}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]>3)for(y in b[x])print(b[x][y])}' data.txt
  ```
- Before gawk 4.0.0:

  ```
  awk '($7 in a){b[$7]=ORS}{c[$7]++;a[$7]=a[$7] b[$7] $0}END{for(x in c)if(c[x]>2)print(a[x])}' data.txt
  ```

Comment: it seems that there are some syntax errors.  @Cyker

Comment: @user3631848 Ahhhhh you need to append your input file.

Comment: I know, but still fail to replicate the output. Here is the link of data.txt. Could you please check ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/1oftxlmj0li8335/tmp.txt?dl=0

Comment: is that possible or any related to the setting of awk ? @Cyker

Comment: @user3631848 Which version of awk are you using? Paste your `awk --version` and error log. The program runs fine on my machine with gawk 4.1.4.

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.8
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2010 Free Software Foundation.
@Cyker

Comment: `awk: {a[$7]++;b[$7]` **[** `c++]=$0}END{for(x in a)if(a[x] > 3)for(y in b` **[** `x])print(b[x]` **[** `y])` **}**

Comment: @user3631848 Arrays of arrays is a feature since gawk 4.0.0. I updated my answer with solutions for pre-4.0.0 versions.

Comment: It works. Thank you SO MUCH. @Cyker. There is a blank line after each match `if(c[x]>3)` through......, I can manage that.

Comment: @user3631848 That's weird. You shouldn't need any further processing as the scripts here have considered and removed blank lines. But I don't have your input so that I cannot test. If you still have problems then you should paste an alternative input. The input you gave above doesn't have a column repeated more than 3 times so it outputs nothing (as it should).

Comment: I pasted a dropbox link for the input. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1oftxlmj0li8335/tmp.txt?dl=0)   If you select  `c[x]>2` , you should be able to have some output. @Cyker

Comment: @user3631848 That's surely a bug that has been fixed. There shouldn't be any unexpected lines when using awk.

Comment: It works perfectly. @Cyker . Now, let me try to understand how it works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pipe it to `awk` to check if the occurrences are greater than 3?

```
awk '{count[$7]++} END {for (word in count) print word, count[word]}' Nofilter.txt | awk '$2 > 3'
```

This will check the output and tell you which lines had occurrences above your chosen cutoff.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, to get the corresponding line in Nofile.txt  if $2 > 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

if your `awk` doesn't support multi dimension arrays you can try this

```
$ awk '{k=$7; c[k]++; a[k]=(k in a)?a[k] ORS $0:$0} 
    END{for(k in c) if(c[k]>3) print a[k]}' file
```

**Explanation**

> `k=$7` set key as field 7
>   `c[k]++`  increment counter for key
>   `a[k]=(k in a)?a[k] ORS $0:$0` append rows with record separator in
>   between (join), special care for the first time `!(k in a)`, since
>   `a[k]=a[k] ORS $0` will start with extra record separator.
>   `END{...` when done, print all satisfying condition.

Comment: This one works. Could you please explain a bit ? Especially, this part `a[k]=(k in a)?a[k] ORS $0:$0`